# Getting a nullpointer exception when using when().thenreturn() in mockito

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito, junit5

I have a mockito junit's test using the command below. The variable serviceTask is an Interface's instancie called ServiceTask. I'm using a @Mock in the declarection

**Declaraction:**

```
@Mock 
private ServiceTask
```

**Command Line:**

```
Mockito.when(serviceTask.getTask(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(new Task());
```

Stack Trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)     at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
> at
> org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
> at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)     at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
> org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
> at
> org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: I often do it this way:   `Mockito.doReturn(new Task()).when(serviceTask).getTask(org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong()));`

Comment: I tried it and the nullPointer persist. I saw there is a check inside the method `serviceTask.getTask()` that it tests an atributted the class Task. Then the result is null to the `new Task()`, this ckeck failed. How could I resolve this?

Comment: @LucianaOliveira do you use `MockitoJunitRunner` to run the test?

Comment: Yes, I do. @HariHaravelan, I use this command line `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` before the `public class`. It's so difficult to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for NPE if it happens at the line of code you mentioned above is `serviceTask` is `null`.

If you're not using the correct test runner which can help you to initialise the mock instance, then you can actually initialise them manually in your `setUp` method by using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

But if you already did so or used the correct test runner, then probably you linked to a wrong line of code. Try to debug yourself again.

Your stack trace doesn't look like it caused from your linked line of code.

Comment: The question with only one line for declaration and one line for the test code, means you assume that you are correct for everything else, this could be a wrong assumption.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. The problem is not in the Mockito's syntax. I found an object that it is null. So the NPE is the Java exception, not the mockito's syntax. Thanks a lot to spend your time in this simple question.